# Retrieving a subset of data from MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

If I have a collection similar to:

```js
[
    { "test": [ { "a": 1, "b": 2 }, { "a": 10, "b": 1 } ] },
    { "test": [ { "a": 5, "b": 1 }, { "a": 14, "b": 2 } ] },
    ...
]
```

How do I obtain only a subset of data consisting of the `a` values when `b` is `2`? In SQL, this would be something similar to:

```
SELECT test.a FROM collection WHERE test.b = 2
```

I do understand that I can limit what data I get with something like:

```
collection.find({ }, { "test.a": 1 })
```

But that returns all the `a` values. How can I limit it so that it returns only the values in which `b` is `2` (the `WHERE test.b = 2` part of the SQL equivalent)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by adding a selector object as the first parameter of your `find` call and using the [`$elemMatch`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/projection/elemMatch/) projection operator:

```
collection.find({ 'test.b': 2 }, { test: { $elemMatch: { b: 2 } }, 'test.a': 1 })
```

But this will only return the first `test` array element per-doc where `b` is 2.  You would need to use the aggregation framework if there can be multiple b:2 elements in your `test` arrays.

Comment: Since he mentions value*s* I suppose he can't use this and will have to use aggregation-framework/map-reduce. Worth noting that the aggregation framework is quite slow though.  Even when using map-reduce some users have found these types of queries to be over 20 times slower than equivalent SQL queries on an RDBMS [http://stackoverflow.com/a/2613106/324381].  Sub-document querying seems to be a bit a of a weak spot with MongoDB at the moment.